# dynamic refresh item oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

How do I refreshing an oracle APEX  item automatically after a specified interval to get true value .

type :- sql query return single row

the item value :-

```
    select (sysdate - created_date) from 
       crm_table 
       where id=:p15_id
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a new hidden Page Item e.g: P15_HIDDEN_REFRESH_ITEM

2) Create a Dynamic Action on Page Load (Page Event = Page Load) and select Action -> 'Execute Javascript Code' and add this Javascript code: ( Change 5000 to the millisecods you want (your interval) ):

`setInterval( ()=> { $s('P15_HIDDEN_REFRESH_ITEM', 'refresh') }, 5000 );`

3) Right Click on the P15_HIDDEN_REFRESH_ITEM Page item and add a 'Change' Dynamic Action and Select 'Execute PL/SQL Code'
Example:

`select (sysdate - created_date)
   INTO :P15_YOUR_PAGE_ITEM
   from crm_table 
  where id=:p15_id`

4) Add p15_id to Items to Submit and add P15_YOUR_PAGE_ITEM to Items to Return.

Done.

**Note:** No need to clear P15_HIDDEN_REFRESH_ITEM, it will continue to fire the Change Event when changing the value 'refresh' to the same value 'refresh'.